# Adding new Keys to a Dictionary

Tags: python, list

```
lst = {}

try:
    lst[someKey].append(someValue)
except KeyError:
    lst[someKey] = []
    lst[someKey].append(someValue) # redundant ?
```

Is there a better way to add to a non-existing key ? In PHP etc it'll create it on its own.

Comment: Doesn't `{}` make `lst` a dictionary ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lst = collections.defaultdict(list)`

Comment: And don't forget to `import collections`.

Comment: To clarify, calling `lst[newkey].append(something)` will add newkey if it doesn't already exist, with an empty list as a value (the result of calling `list()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
lst[someKey] = lst.get(someKey, []) + [someValue]
```